# How to Access a variable in a filestream loaded in list container

Tags: c++, c++11

I am the new kid in the block, studying C++. I have loaded a file stream in a list container, using variables. I want to be able to access and change the value of any of those variables. I've been trying for weeks to no avail. Can somebody help?

**This is the external text file: flightBoard1.txt**

```
  Delta 3431 Paris JFK
  Usair 2275 EWR London
  Delta 1500 Bonn Milan
```

**This is the main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template<class T, class U, class V>
void changeFlight(list<string> &myFlight, T loc, U value, V newVal);

int main()
{
    string _company;
    int _flight;
    string _origin;
    string _destination;

    list<string> flightBoard;
    stringstream *ssPtr;
    int counter = 0;

    ifstream myFile("flightBoard1.txt");
    while(myFile >> _company >> _flight >> _origin >> _destination ){
        ++counter;
        ssPtr = new stringstream; // you want to put each line in a different slot in the flightBoard list object
        *ssPtr << counter << " " << _company << "\t" << _flight << "\t" << _origin << "\t" << _destination << endl;
        flightBoard.push_back(ssPtr->str()); // You need an arrow, this is a pointer

    }

    list<string>::iterator it;
    for(it = flightBoard.begin(); it != flightBoard.end(); it++){
        cout << *it ;
    }

    int oldFlight, newFlight;
    cout << endl << "Enter old flight number: ";
    cin >> oldFlight;
    cout << "Enter new flight number: ";
    cin >> newFlight;

    changeFlight(flightBoard, ssPtr, oldFlight, newFlight);

    delete ssPtr;
    myFile.close();


    return 0;
}

template<class T, class U, class V>
void changeFlight(list<string> &myFlight, T loc, U value, V newVal){
    list<string>::iterator it;
    cout << endl << "Flight: " << value << " has been changed to: " << newVal << endl;
    for(it = myFlight.begin(); it != myFlight.end(); it++){
        // THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING A PROBLEM
        // PLEASE UN-COMMENT BELOW TO SEE PROBLEM
        /*if(it -> myFlight -> loc -> value){
            value = newVal;
        }*/ 

    }

}
```

Comment: Explain why you think your program is not working as it should.

Comment: The program works fine, but if you un-comment the 'if(){..}' section in the changeFlight() function definition at the bottom of the code, you will see where I am trying to access the variables in the list container thru the iterator.

Comment: @yorxman `myFlight` list consists of strings, so you cannot access it's parts in that way. You should first parse the string again. I suggest a better solution. Check the answer bellow.

Comment: @Nikita, Thank you for input, I tried your code and it works fine. BUT that's not the way I want to go. I could've used a struct or two or simple classes to solve the problem, but I know for sure that there must be a way, and an easy way, I am sure, to access to those variables, nice and clean. Think about it, those variables, although loaded into a list string, belong to a stringstream object which can hold any kind of data, thus accessing ssPtr to further reach any of the variables it holds, is, I am certain, possible. Hopefully, someone will come along with a better solution. Again, Thanx!

Comment: @yorxman In your code snippet `ssPtr` contains only the last `stringstream` because it's recreated on each `while` iteration. So only data for the last flight is there. If you fix it, you can pull flight information, but anyway you will need the other `stringstream` instance to put changed information. There is no clean way to do in-place `stringstream` modification.

Comment: @Nikita thanks for your advice and input. I didn't realize that only the data of the last iteration was in the container. I guess I'm gonna have to find a way to load a different stringstream object on each slot at each of the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem I think you should use the better structure for storage of your flights. `string` is not a good type if you need to manipulate data further. I suggest to introduce class `Flight`:

```
class Flight
{
  public:
    string company;
    int flight;
    string origin;
    string destination;

    Flight(const string& _company, int _flight, const string& _origin, const string& _destination)
      : company(_company), flight(_flight), origin(_origin), destination(_destination)
    {
    }

    string ToString() const
    {
      stringstream printer;
      printer << company << "\t" << flight << "\t" << origin << "\t" << destination << endl;
      return printer.str();
    }
};
```

Also there are a number of problems in code snippet you have posted.

- Memory leak inside `while` loop. You are allocating `ssPtr = new stringstream;` on each iteration, but `delete` it only once at the end.
- `changeFlight` has too much template type arguments. If `U value` should be changed to `V newVal` inside `changeFlight` probably it should have the same types.
- Hard to change type of `flightBoard`, `list<string>` copied everywhere. It's better to create `typedef` for `list<string>` type to make your code simpler. E.g. `typedef list<string> FlightListType;`.

Here is your code with all the mentioned problems fixed:

```
typedef list<Flight> FlightListType;

template<class T>
void changeFlight(FlightListType& myFlight, T value, T newVal);

int main()
{
    string _company;
    int _flight;
    string _origin;
    string _destination;

    FlightListType flightBoard;

    ifstream myFile("flightBoard1.txt");
    while(myFile >> _company >> _flight >> _origin >> _destination )
    {
      flightBoard.push_back(Flight(_company, _flight, _origin, _destination)); 
    }

    FlightListType::const_iterator it;
    int counter = 0;
    for(it = flightBoard.begin(); it != flightBoard.end(); it++)
    {
      cout << counter << " " << (*it).ToString();
      ++counter;
    }

    int oldFlight, newFlight;
    cout << endl << "Enter old flight number: ";
    cin >> oldFlight;
    cout << "Enter new flight number: ";
    cin >> newFlight;

    changeFlight(flightBoard, oldFlight, newFlight);

    myFile.close();

    return 0;
}

template<class T>
void changeFlight(FlightListType& myFlight, T value, T newVal)
{
    FlightListType::iterator it;
    cout << endl << "Flight: " << value << " has been changed to: " << newVal << endl;
    for(it = myFlight.begin(); it != myFlight.end(); it++)
    {
      if ((*it).flight == value)
      {
        // TODO: Here you can do with the Flight what ever you need
        // For example change it's number
        (*it).flight = newVal;
      }
    }
}
```